# oracle c# how to bind a variable with like

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have this query

```
 string query = "SELECT * from IMALSO3.V_BN_IVR_ACCT_BAL_MNO WHERE PHONENO Like '%':mobileNumber";

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("mobileNumber", phone8Digits);
```

but it seems that i am binding wrong,

what is the correct way plase?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the single quote, and put the wildcard marker `%` into the value itself, not into the query string:

```
string query = "SELECT * from IMALSO3.V_BN_IVR_ACCT_BAL_MNO WHERE PHONENO Like :mobileNumber";

using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn)) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("mobileNumber", "%"+phone8Digits);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `'%'` from command text and pass it while adding parameter like:

```
string query = "SELECT * from IMALSO3.V_BN_IVR_ACCT_BAL_MNO WHERE PHONENO Like :mobileNumber";
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("mobileNumber", "%" + phone8Digits);
```

If you want to compare `phone8Digits` like contains then use:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("mobileNumber", "%" + phone8Digits + "%");
```